# Sending official transcript with mistakes

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have been admitted to a Ph.D. program in the US recently. I have to send my official academic transcript. The university issued me a transcript that has a number of courses with no grades written next to them. These were added by mistake. They were not included in the unofficial scanned copy that I used in my graduate application. Would it harm my application if I sent this transcript?

Also, I have received a transcript from my university (signed and sealed envelope) in February. Can I send it as an official transcript if I have it since February? My school does not have a mechanism in place for sending transcripts directly.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you have received two copies of your official transcript, one you opened to identify this error, and one you have not?

Comment: I was not clear. I have a sealed and signed transcript that has these errors (courses I did not take were mentioned with missing grades). I received it in February.

Comment: If it is sealed, how do you know it has these errors?

Comment: What can you do to get the errors corrected?

Comment: Because I have scanned it before the university sealed the file. I did not look at the PDF carefully. I just discovered these errors when i opened the PDF

Comment: Ask the school. However, the registrar office is closed due to this coronavirus.

Comment: That's unusual to my US ears. You should talk to the school you were admitted to

Comment: "I have been admitted..."  "Would it harm my application..."  This is inconsistent.  Please fix it.

Comment: Can you delete the last paragraph? There is supposed to be only one question per post.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it harm my application if I sent this transcript?

Not if done correctly. This is one of those "special circumstances" where there is likely no established rule; you just have to contact a human and explain the situation. What you can do is:

1. Send the transcript with the errors
2. Reach out to the person in charge of admissions (either the professor and/or an administrator) at the University and explain that there is an error on the transcript.
3. Reach out to someone at your own University to see if they can send some kind of official notice to verify that there is an error.

Once everyone is aware of the problem, it should not be an issue. They can verify with your university that the transcript is indeed an error.

Of course, the best solution would be to contact your university to see if they can remove the errors and correct the transcript. But if this is impossible, then the above should be good enough.